# Check encrypted password on Login ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a method to encrypt an user's password as the following:

```
        public string EncryptPassword(string password)
        {
            // Encrypt password
            byte[] salt = new byte[128 / 8]; // Generate a 128-bit salt using a secure PRNG
            using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
            {
                rng.GetBytes(salt);
            }

            string encryptedPassw = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
                password: password,
                salt: salt,
                prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
                iterationCount: 10000,
                numBytesRequested: 256 / 8
            ));

            return encryptedPassw;
        }
```

But I am stuck at a problem: I want the user to log in but I don't know how to read the password properly when logging in. Can someone help out who knows how to solve it or experiences the same problem.

Comment: This is not related to the <sql> language. You can add the tag for your dbms instead.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean; you take what the user typed into your login form, run it through the `EncryptPassw` method and compare the result with the data stored in the DB for that user. No match = wrong password

Comment: @CaiusJard I have tried it but it generates a new hashed password when I run it with that method.

Comment: You stored the salt along with the user, so you could use it next time?

Comment: How can I store the salt along the user?

Comment: Salting and hashing passwords is ***very*** well documented here and elsewhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I store the salt along the user?

Just add a property to the user, like below:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public byte[] StoredSalt { get; set; }
    //other properties...
}
```

When User entered a new password, you need to encrypt it with the same salt, then compare it with the encrypted password in the database.

You can refer to the below codes:

Define a new class for temporarily Use:

```
public class HashSalt
{
    public string Hash { get; set; }
    public byte[] Salt { get; set; }
}
```

Something like Register and Login:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Register(User user)
{
    var hashsalt = EncryptPassword(user.Password);
    user.Password = hashsalt.Hash;
    user.StoredSalt = hashsalt.Salt;
    _context.Users.Add(user);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login(User loginUser)
{
    var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == loginUser.Name);
    var isPasswordMatched = VerifyPassword(loginUser.Password, user.StoredSalt, user.Password);
    if (isPasswordMatched)
    {
        //Login Successfull
    }
    else
    {
        //Login Failed
    }

    return View();
}
public HashSalt EncryptPassword(string password)
{
    byte[] salt = new byte[128 / 8]; // Generate a 128-bit salt using a secure PRNG
    using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    {
        rng.GetBytes(salt);
    }
    string encryptedPassw = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
        password: password,
        salt: salt,
        prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
        iterationCount: 10000,
        numBytesRequested: 256 / 8
    ));
    return new HashSalt { Hash = encryptedPassw , Salt = salt };
}
    
public bool VerifyPassword(string enteredPassword, byte[] salt, string storedPassword)
{
    string encryptedPassw = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
        password: enteredPassword,
        salt: salt,
        prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
        iterationCount: 10000,
        numBytesRequested: 256 / 8
    ));
    return encryptedPassw == storedPassword;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for your effort I really appreciate it! I will try this again tomorrow and I will let you know how it went!

Comment: How should I store the salt in the database? What datatype do I need?

Comment: You can use `varbinary` data type to store it.

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to verify the password before authentication, then there is no need to decrypt the saved password but rather to encrypt the one entered in order to then compare the correspondence.

```
//...
if(EncryptPassword(enteredPwd)==encryptedSavedPwd){
//authentication
}else{
//password error
}
```

Comment: No it's encrypted in the database I need a way to get the data and check if it's matching the user input.

Comment: I don't understand where is the problem. You want the code on "how to get data" or You are facing issue with "check matching" ?. Database or not, you can get encrypted password within a variable and compare with entered password (encrypted too)

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with @elgsylvain85 you don't have to decrypt the password to validate for credentials when users logs in. You can encrypt the password user enters and match it against the data store.

That said the best practice for storing passwords is hashing instead of encrypting. Hashed password can not be decoded even if the hacker gets access to the data store.

Following is the documentation for .NET hashing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/ensuring-data-integrity-with-hash-codes